# Why is the Page Template dropdown menu using the wrong file name?

Tags: theme-development, page-template, page-attributes

This is strange.

I have a file, `page_market.php`, that is named "Market Main Page". It WAS being used when I chose that page template, but now it is not working at all. Instead, it looks like I'm using the default template.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts, and I finally decided to search for [where a page template's value is stored in the database](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-page-templates-value-is-stored-in-database). This gave me my first clue, because I found `single-sponsor.php`, the name of one of the other template files I'm building.

I was confused as to why this could be the case, and looked at the HTML of the actual dropdown menu WordPress generated:

```
<select name="page_template" id="page_template">
  <option value="default">Default Template</option>
  <option value="page-custom.php">Custom Page Example</option>
  <option value="single-sponsor.php" selected="selected">Market Main Page</option>
</select>
```

Pretty clearly choosing `single-sponsor.php`.

Why would it be doing that?

**Because I told it to.**

I had copied the code from `page-market.php` into `single-sponsor.php` to start developing a new page template.

At the top of `single-sponsor.php`?

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Market Main Page
*/
?>
```

Right.

Stupid mistake. But I thought it was worth writing up, in case the same thing happens to someone else.

I changed the name before realizing that I didn't want this file to show up in my template list, so I removed the code.

Foo.